# Can nmon use Data Capture Mode in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: performance, monitor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to capture using the below command in WSL Ubuntu.

`moauris@AUR00101:~$ /pp/nmon/nmon -s 60 -c 1440 -f -m /mnt/c/Perf_data/`

It was supposed to run as a process until 1440 captures, but it did not. It ran and immediately end.

Please guide me to the correct way to capture nmon, or it cannot be done in WSL? Thanks!

Comment: Windows version? distro? any strace report? Your command works for me in Windows build 17704

Comment: Thanks, @Biswapriyo,

[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      17134  0

Linux distro:

Linux AUR00101 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #81-Microsoft Sun May 20 01:14:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux